# cancelAnimationFrame inside of object method not working

Tags: javascript, constructor, bind, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

`cancelAnimationFrame()` does not seem to work when called inside an object's method. I have tried binding the `this` value to the callback function ([as demonstrated on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout) with `setTimeout`) but I received a TypeError when using `cancelAnimationFrame()`. I then tried setting the `this` value to a local variable called `_this` and called `cancelAnimationFrame()` again. That time, I did not receive an error but the animation itself is still playing. How do I cancel the animation?

I have recreated the issue I am having below. If you open a console window, you will see that the animation is still running.

```js
function WhyWontItCancel() {
  this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.canvas.width = 200;
  this.canvas.height = 10;
  document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
  this.draw = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.draw.fillStyle = "#f00";
  this.position = 0;
};

WhyWontItCancel.prototype.play = function() {
  if (this.position <= 190) {
    this.draw.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 10);
    this.draw.fillRect(this.position, 0, 10, 10);
    this.position += 2;
  } else {
    //window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.animation.bind(this));
    var _this = this;
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(_this.animation);
    console.log("still running");
  }

  this.animation = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.play.bind(this));
};

var animation = new WhyWontItCancel();
animation.play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you miss two things here. First, `this.animation = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.play.bind(this));` line is invoked *always* when `play()` is called. Contrary to what you might think, `cancelAnimationFrame` only removes the previously requested RAF call. Strictly speaking, it's not even necessary here. Second, you don't have to bind on each RAF call; you might do it just once:

```
function AnimatedCanvas() {
  this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.canvas.width = 200;
  this.canvas.height = 10;
  document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
  this.draw = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.draw.fillStyle = "#f00";
  this.position = 0;

  this.play = this.play.bind(this); // takes `play` from prototype object
};

AnimatedCanvas.prototype.play = function() {
  if (this.position <= 190) {
    this.draw.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 10);
    this.draw.fillRect(this.position, 0, 10, 10);
    this.position += 2;
    this.animationId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.play);
  }
};
```

You might want to add cancel into your prototype to be able to stop your animation, for example:

```
AnimatedCanvas.prototype.cancel = function() {
  if (this.animationId) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationId);
  }
};
```

... but the point is, it's not useful in the use case described in the question.